# Where are my starred questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks, tag-watching

I star multiple questions a day. I can't find them when I look through my [favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2909897/mbigras?tab=favorites) tab in my profile.

I've read through [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) and [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/is-there-a-way-to-see-all-my-favorite-questions) but I believe there is a misunderstanding.

I'm trying to find the questions that I personally have marked as starred sorted by most recent.

My last favorite is from April 20 but I mark about 4-5 questions as favorites every day in the hopes that I'll be able to go back and find them. It doesn't make sense to me why they aren't showing up in my profile in the "favorites" tab.

[image]

- Where are the questions that I've marked as starred questions (aka favorited questions)?

Comment: The date in the list is not when you favorited the question but it is instead the date if the last activity on the question.  Are you favoriting old or new questions?

Comment: Hmm maybe, I don't always look at the date when I mark a question as favorited is it possible to find the questions in order of newest date time that I've added them?

Comment: They already are in the order you have added them in.  It is just the data is not the added to list date.

Comment: You are sorting the favourites by *date the post was created*. Try going to the `added` tab instead.

Comment: Good spot @MartijnPieters.  I thought he was on added and missed it said newest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have sorted the favourites by *newest*; this sorts on when the post was *created*, newest to oldest, not by when you starred the post:

> [image: screenshot from OP with newest sort option circled]

That's an excerpt from your own screenshot, focusing on the sorting options in the top right.

Switch to the *added* tab to see the posts in the order you starred them, most recent post on top:

> [image: favourites tab for OP, with added sort option enabled and circled]